# ARIMA in R only in train set

Tags: r, arima

I'm trying to predict the last 12 months of a time serie of 600 observations (so train will be 1 to 588 and test 589 to 600). I already have this data but I want to do the prediction to be able to get some error estimation. So I was building the ARIMA model with all my data but the last 12 months like this:

```
st2 <-ts(st[1:588], start = 1965, frequency = 12)
modelst2 <- arima(st2,order = c(0,1,1),seasonal = list(order = c(0,0,2)))
```

And I got this ARIMA coefficients:

```
Call:
arima(x = st2, order = c(0, 1, 1), seasonal = list(order = c(0, 0, 2)))

Coefficients:
         ma1    sma1     sma2
      0.1067  0.1732  -0.0243
s.e.  0.0332  0.0427   0.0436

sigma^2 estimated as 4.031:  log likelihood = -1242.29,  aic = 2492.58
```

But then I did this modifications to "reduce" the lenght of the code:

```
model <- arima(st[1:588], order=c(0,1,1), seasonal=list(order=c(0,0,2)))
```

And I was surprised that the ARIMA coefficients changed to this:

```
Call:
arima(x = ex5[1:588], order = c(0, 1, 1), seasonal = list(order = c(0, 0, 2)))

Coefficients:
         ma1     sma1    sma2
      0.1699  -0.0906  0.3022
s.e.  0.1187   0.1209  0.0457

sigma^2 estimated as 3.78:  log likelihood = -1223.32,  aic = 2454.63
```

Why am I getting different coefficients if I'm using the exact same data??
Thanks!:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By "reducing the length of the code" you're also losing information about `frequency` that you specified on the time series. You can also set `period` in the `arima` function that should lead to the same results.

```
model <- arima(st[1:588], order=c(0,1,1), seasonal=list(order=c(0,0,2), period = 12))
```

Comment: Thanks Jan! One additional question, if I loaded the time series(st) like this: st <- ts(read.csv("dd.txt", header=F), start=c(1965,1),frequency=12), which of both methods would be apropiate to get the first 588 observarions to get the frequency right? If using the first one, would I be duplicating the information about frequency?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are you asking whether to specify frequency in `ts` or `arima` function? I'd say it doesn't matter